# Proca Lagrangian (calculus issue)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, action

I have the following action:
\begin{equation}
S_{Proca}=\int d^4x\Big(-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}m^2A_\mu A^\mu\Big)
\end{equation}
where $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$.
After expanding the $F_{\mu\nu}$ tensor and renaming dummy indices I got:
\begin{equation}
S_{Proca}=\int d^4x\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu+\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu-\frac{1}{2}m^2A_\mu A^\mu\Big)
\end{equation}
while, according to my teacher's notes I should get:
\begin{equation}
S_{Proca}=\int d^4x\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu A_\nu\partial^\mu A^\nu+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2A_\mu A^\mu\Big)
\end{equation}
I can't find the (surely simple) passage that leads from my result to my teacher's result. At some point he mentions an "integration by parts". I didn't use any integration by parts, maybe it's a missing passage, but I don't understand where I should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fraf they are just algebraic sobstitutions, i attach the picture with the passages you need to make. 
[image]

Comment: The first line is just absolutely wrong, $F^{\mu\nu}$ must always remain anti-symmetric. You don't need that to arrive to the expression the OP has.

Answer (score 5):

Using integration by parts, we can add total derivatives to the integrand without changing the action. Explicitly$$\int d^4 x 1\partial_\mu V^\mu=-\int d^4 x \partial_\mu1\, V^\mu=0.$$In this case, what's been added is $\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\left( A^\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu-A^\nu\partial_\nu A^\mu\right)$. I'll leave it to you to show this converts $\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu A_\nu \partial^\nu A^\mu$ to $\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu A^\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu$, as required. There's one tricky step, in which we use$$A^\nu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu A^\mu=A^\mu\partial_\nu\partial_\mu A^\nu=A^\mu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu$$(the first $=$ sign changes the dummy indices while the second commutes partial derivatives).

Comment: Thanks J.G. I can't accept both answers but I upvoted you, very useful ;)

Comment: Are there some extra deltas in the final eq?

Comment: Yes innisfree, you're right, I guess it's a typo. I didn't even notice it since my struggle was solved with the first few lines of J.G. answer. I read the rest very quickly.